# Compiling error Nullreference

Tags: c#, compilation

I'm compiling a program which was originally build in Visual C# 2005. I'am using visual C# 2010. And I keep getting "NullReference Execption was unhandled" errors when running the program on the following functions:
The error occurs on the line with DataBuffer. DataBuffer is an private string set to null on initialisation.

```
if (DataBuffer.Contains(ok)) 
            {
                okFound = true;
            }
```

and

```
    string temp = getLine(DataBuffer.Substring(mylocation));
    if (!checkTypeFound())
    {
        if (temp != null)
        {
            parseDeviceType(temp);
        }
        checkTypeFound();
    }
```

When I check what the value of DataBuffer is in the code above (when I get the error) this is not null. It actually contains the data I expect.
DataBuffer information is loaded in this function:

```
private void ser1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    while (ser1.BytesToRead > 0)
    {
        string data = ser1.ReadExisting();
        DataBuffer += data;
    }
}
```

The serial port is opened somewhere else in the code. There have been no changes to the code only the compiler is different. What line should I add, and where to solve this error? Note, I can prevent this error from happening using an if and try-catch statement. But this is not what I'm looking for, I need this code to work.
This application has not been changed in any way other than the compiler.

Comment: You've shown *snippets* of code, but you've given no indication of why you'd expect `DataBuffer` to be non-null by the time you reach the first snippet.

Comment: Does this error actually happen during compilation? or at runtime? What is `DataBuffer`, and when is it assigned a value?

Comment: On another note: concatenating stings repeatedly is a bit of a faux-pas - should really use `StringBuilder`

Comment: @ShellShock not true; you are allowed to concatenate strings where either or both is null

Comment: You can try and assign the string to string.Empty and try the code is it gives the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if `DataBuffer` is `null` before you call its methods.

```
if (DataBuffer != null && DataBuffer.Contains(ok)) 
{
    okFound = true;
}

// or simpler:
okFound = (DataBuffer != null && DataBuffer.Contains(ok));
```

and your second code snipped should check for `null` as well.

```
string temp = String.Empty;

if (DataBuffer != null)
    temp = getLine(DataBuffer.Substring(mylocation));

if (!checkTypeFound())
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(temp))
        parseDeviceType(temp);

    checkTypeFound();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:

```
if (DataBuffer != null && DataBuffer.Contains(ok)) 
{
   okFound = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the value of `DataBuffer` to something other than null in your constructor. If you can't do that then you may set it to `string.Empty` instead of null to avoid null exception. But it always better to **check for null** before initiating an instance method on object.